# Is $x = \arccos ( \frac{3}{5})$ a rational number?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

Wolfram tells us $x = \arccos ( \frac{3}{5})$ is an irrational number. How can we prove it? (Without using a computer obviously)

Comment: A computer cannot calculate whether such a number is rational. Wolfram Alpha has some knowledge about irrational numbers and can tell whether particular types of numbers are rational.

Comment: It is not rational. See [Niven's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem), which links to this [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Niven's_Theorem).

Comment: $x$ is even transcendental (See my answer)

Comment: @Peter Well, that depends on whether the result of $\arccos$ is in degrees or radians. In radians you are correct, but for degrees there are a few angles given by Niven's theorem where you have a rational angle with a rational cosine and 3/5 is not one of them.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis True, but without additional context this expression should be interpreted to be in radians. By the way, do we know whether the expression (in degree) is transcendental, or can we only apply Niven's theorem to show the irrationality ?

Comment: @Flaffo Do you mean the arccos in degree or in radians ? In both cases, we have an irrational number, but the methods to decide it are different.

Comment: @Peter The original problem was to prove that $a_n = r cos (\alpha + n \theta)$ with $cos \theta = \frac {3}{5}$ is not periodic. In order to be periodic, $2 \pi = T \theta$ or $360= T \theta$ where $T$ is the period and \theta has to be rational. I don't think it makes a difference whether it is in radians or degrees

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x=\arccos(\frac{3}{5})$

Then, we have $\cos(x)=\frac{3}{5}$

Obviously, we have $x\ne 0$

With the Lindemann-Weierstrass-theorem, we can show that $\cos(x)$ is transcendental for every algebraic non-zero $x$.

Therefore, $x$ cannot be algebraic, since $\frac{3}{5}$ is not transcendental.

Hence $x$ is transcendental, in particular irrational.